# Submit form with ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, github-pages

I'm building a website with GitHub pages and Jekyll.

I want to build a contact form where userss can send emails. For this I'm using  `Formspree` . I created an account and I tried and it's working.
The problem is that when an email is sent, i don't want to redirect the page at default thanks page. I tried to submit it with ajax but something is wrong and for that it's not working!!
As result I have a 404 error. Also URL is changed and it looks like this: `/?name=Name+Lastname&_replyto=test%40hotmail.com&message=Email+content+`
Can somebody help me!
Here's my code:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.13.1/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $("#contact-form").validate({
  submitHandler: function(form) {
    $.ajax({
      url: "//formspree.io/egzontina.krasniqi@hotmail.com", 
      method: "POST",
      data: {
        name: $(form).find("input[name='name']").val(),
        _replyto: $(form).find("input[name='_replyto']").val(),
        message: $(form).find("textarea[name='message']").val()
      },
      dataType: "json",
      success: function() {
        $("#submit-success").fadeIn();
        $("#contact-form").fadeOut();
      },
      error: function() {
        $("#submit-errors").fadeIn();        
      }
    });
  }
});
</script>
```

Here's my html code:

```
 <div id="submit-success" class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible collapse" role="alert">
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
          Message received! I'll be in touch.
 </div>


<div id="submit-errors" class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible collapse" role="alert">
  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
  It looks like there was an error submitting the form. Please try again later.
</div>


<form id="contact-form" class="form" action="/">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="name">Name</label>
    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="name" required placeholder="Name">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="email">Email</label>
    <input class="form-control" type="email" name="_replyto" required placeholder="email@address.com">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="message">Message</label>
    <textarea class="form-control" name="message" placeholder="Message" required rows="5"></textarea>
  </div>
  <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Send">
</form>
```

Comment: What does the Console in your Developer Tools say?

Comment: "it's not working" — That's not a good problem statement. What happens? You've got success and error functions. do either of them fire?

Comment: @Quentin i have a 404 error. The URL is changed and it looks like this: /?name=Name+Lastname&_replyto=test%40hotmail.com&message=My+email+content+

Comment: That's because you're submitting the form (and the action is wrong) and your JS is doing nothing to stop it. Should that validate function stop it submitting?

Comment: @Quentin if I change the action into this: action="//formspree.io/your@email.com" the Js code it's not working too and the page redirects into Formspree thanks page! Can u give a little help!  I followed this link to do that: http://www.austinzentz.com/2015/06/24/contact-forms-in-static-sites.html

Answer (score 3):

Currently, your form is submitting normally. Stop the default action with

```
$('#contact-form').on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: I tried this but the same thing is happening, URL is changed  and i have a 404 error as result!

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `action="/"` from your form, leaving you with:

```
<form id="contact-form" class="form">
```

Try that and let me know what happens.

Yh and change the submit input to a button

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Send</button>
```

@Subhasish contribution is correct too. vote our answers pls.
Let's know if u find it helpful

Comment: thank you for your answer! I changed that but now the page is reloading and only the URL is changing, email it's not sent! URL looks same: /?name=Name+Lastname&_replyto=test%40hotmail.com&message=Email+content+

Answer (score 0):

Remove action from your form and then it will surely work.
Otherwise "/" will be called as a GET request in spite of any other validation that you are following on your client side.

@Dekoy is absolutely correct.
Use this code :
`<form id="contact-form" class="form">`

Comment: thank you for your answer! I changed that but now the page is reloading and only the URL is changing, email it's not sent! URL looks same: /?name=Name+Lastname&_replyto=test%40hotmail.com&message=Email+content+

Comment: Then change input type from submit to button . i.e. `<input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Send">` to `<input class="btn btn-primary" type="button" value="Send">`